# frames not showing

Tags: html, frame, frameset

i'm trying to use frames, but they aren't showing up. I tried using the exact sample (with srcs to my pages) from w3schools, but still when the page loads the frames don't. There's no error provided or anything. They just don't show up at all. I don't get it. I'm using Chrome if that helps.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols

Edit: I found that adding anything other than frames makes all frames disappear. Can a page not have anything but frames using a frameset?

Comment: Under no circumstances show us any code! It would just confuse and distract us. :)

Comment: Well I thought it profoundly obvious by my statement "exact sample [...] from w3schools" that is was the sample from w3schools.http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols Then of course this wouldn't help because it works as opposed to when I use it, and unless you want a full page of html you have to scroll through I can't detect the cause of the problem. I could only assume someone would at least be familiar with the problem and know a solution, or otherwise not bother.

Comment: @Anonymous, well, that sample actually works...so yours is presumably different, no?  Maybe you can try jsfiddle and put your code there.

Comment: I used the exact sample, as stated, with URLS to my pages (of course). I checked the URLs via the source code and they go to pages on my site, so that can't be the problem. I don't know what could be. I used the exact thing aside from srcs.

Comment: It's almost a guarantee that you goofed something up in your own code. Please, post a link or a jsFiddle with your HTML so we can peek at it.

Comment: <frameset cols="25%,50%,25%">

 <frame src="/header.php" />
 <frame src="/test.php" />
 <frame src="/footer.php" />

</frameset> Exactly what you'll see on w3s.

Comment: did you put this code in the w3schools page, and it didn't work? Or doesn't it work locally?

Comment: @anonymous, edit your entry so everyone sees this addition. Also, please include your local folder structure (e.g., /site/ contains /site/index.php, site/footer.php, etc). It's very likely that the pointers are pointing incorrectly. Also, do you have a local server? Are you doing anything with php pages?

Comment: I tried changing it on w3s and adding anything outside of the frameset makes it stop working. Is it impossible to use anything with frames?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but are you running on a webserver, or just locally? IF you are running locally, the leading slash will not work.

Comment: How should the w3schools page know where to find your local files? Don't you get 404's in the frames?

Comment: @Anonymous, try not to get frustrated. Do not assume something is wrong with the HTML spec for frames. There is something you don't understand, or a typo.

Comment: @Byron lol, "select" Isn’t Broken

Comment: @Rian When I tested it it was on my site... I then fiddled with the sample on w3schools.

Comment: See http://w3fools.com/ and http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9605a.html

Comment: @Anonymous But are the paths to the files right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't have a body element and a frameset element on the same page. See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.2). Oh by the way, DO NOT use frames, they are evil.

Comment: Or anything other than html for that matter. I found out by testing a lot of different things and coming to the conclusion that frames simply aren't meant to be used within a page with other content. If only someone just knew and answered that before.

Comment: You can use iframes (inline frames) within a page with other content.